# Two word computer term ending in word "complex" meaning computers connected together

Tags: terminology, computer-networks

I remember seeing a Computer Science jargon which means multiple computers connected together; a network. It ends in the word "complex" and the first word (I cannot remember this but I shall guess to the best of my memory) is taken from some science-fiction franchise or from mythology. It could also be a proper noun used in a way unrelated to Computer Science. I have spent days looking for this and any help is most welcome.

Comment: Beowulf cluster?

Comment: OMG! Yes! Thank you so much! It ends in "cluster"! Thank you!